# Print row ID at which all other row values are smaller than 0.05

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with confidence intervals for different parameters (P1-P4) and an ID for each model evaluation. I want to print the first ID at which the values for all parameters (in the rows) are <0.05.The output of the print statement should be 5, since at ID=5, that's the first time all values in columns (P1-P4) are smaller than 0.05.

**Dataframe:**

```
   ID    P1    P2    P3    P4
0   1  0.50  0.06  0.20  0.01
1   2  0.20  0.05  0.15  0.01
2   3  0.10  0.05  0.10  0.01
3   4  0.08  0.04  0.06  0.01
4   5  0.04  0.04  0.04  0.01
5   6  0.03  0.04  0.02  0.01
```

**Tried code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   "P1": [0.50,0.20,0.10,0.08,0.04,0.03],
                   "P2": [0.06,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.04,0.04],
                   "P3": [0.20,0.15,0.10,0.06,0.04,0.02],
                   "P4": [0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01]})
print(df)

print(df[df.loc[:, ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']] < 0.05].ID[0])
print(df[(df.loc[:,['P1','P2','P3','P4']] < 0.05), 'ID'])
```

**Desired output from the print statement:** 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if `True`s in all selected columns and then select first `ID` if sure always exist at least one matched `ID`:

```
print(df.loc[df[['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']].lt(0.05).all(axis=1), 'ID'].iat[0])
5
```

If not sure if exist this value use `next` with `iter trick`:

```
print(next(iter(df.loc[df[['P1','P2','P3','P4']].lt(0.05).all(axis=1), 'ID']), 'no match'))
5


print(next(iter(df.loc[df[['P1','P2','P3','P4']].lt(0.005).all(axis=1), 'ID']), 'no match'))
no match
```